# How to view and remove cron jobs in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, cron

I'm new to drupal 7 and I need to see what cron is running.  I had a cron Feeds scheduled to run once a day and it is no longer needed.  I deleted the feed but the cron is still running.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has an auto-cron implementation, to disable it go to mysite.com/admin/config/system/cron and set **'Run cron every'** to **'Never'**.

If that doesn't work check there are no lingering jobs scheduled in your server's [`crontab`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=crontab).

Hope that helps

EDIT

Just to add, you can't 'see' what jobs are running in Drupal as such because there is only one - the job you can cancel by setting the afore-mentioned setting to 'Never'

Answer (score 0):

Use for this module [ultimate_cron](http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)
you may read extended log message and control of all cron jobs.